# Run program without messing around with functions.php inside theme folder

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm making my own wordpress plugin. I made on off program like this:

```
require 'connection.php';
    $optionQuery = "SELECT * FROM wpex12_achan_plugin";
    $dataQuery = $connection->query($optionQuery);
    $data = array();
    if( mysqli_num_rows($dataQuery) ) {
        $data = $dataQuery->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
    };

    //option on off
    $option1 = array(
        'name' => 'option1',
        'options' => array(
            array(
                'text' => 'off',
                'value' => 0,
                'checked' => ($data['shareButton'] == 0) ? 'checked="checked"' : ''
                    ),
            array(
                'text' => 'on',
                'value' => 1,
                'checked' => ($data['shareButton'] == 1) ? 'checked="checked"' : ''
                    )
                )

            );

add_action("admin_menu", "addMenu");
function addMenu(){
    add_menu_page("Achan Plugin", "Achan Ganteng", 4, "example-options", "insideMenu", plugins_url('/image/icon.png',__FILE__));
}

function insideMenu(){
    global $connection, $option1, $dataQuery, $data;

    ?>
        <!DOCTYPE html>
        <html lang="en">
        <head>
            <meta charset="UTF-8">
            <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        </head>
        <body>  
        <h1>Welcome To Achan Custom Plugin</h1>
        <form action="" method="POST">
            <div class ="share-button">
                <label for="buttonshare">Share Social Widget inside Forum: </label> &nbsp
                <?php if(is_array($option1) && $option1['options']) : ?>
                <?php foreach ($option1['options'] as $option) : ?>
                <label class="checkbox">
                    <input type="radio" name="<?php echo $option1 ['name'] ?>" value ="<?php echo $option['value'] ?>" <?php echo $option['checked'] ?> >
                    <span class="text"><?php echo $option['text'] ?></span>
                </label>
                <?php endforeach ?>
                <?php endif ?>
            
            </div>

            <br />
            <div class="submit">
                <input type="submit" value="Submit" name="submitClick" class="button">
            </div>
        
        </form>


        </body>
        </html>
    <?php
        //if submit clicked
        if(isset($_POST['submitClick'])){
            $getValue = isset ($_POST['option1']) ? $_POST['option1'] : 0;

            if(mysqli_num_rows($dataQuery)){
                $updateQuery = "UPDATE wpex12_achan_plugin SET shareButton = $getValue";
            }
            else{
                $updateQuery = "INSERT INTO wpex12_achan_plugin (shareButton) VALUES ($getValue)";
            }
            if(!$connection -> query($updateQuery)){
                echo ("Error description" . $mysqli -> error);
            }
            $connection -> close();
            header('Location: http://localhost/nameofweb/wp-admin/admin.php?page=example-options');    
        }
    }


?>
```

and also i made hook like this:

```
<?php
require 'connection.php';
    $optionQuery = "SELECT * FROM wpex12_achan_plugin";
    $dataQuery = $connection->query($optionQuery);
    $data = array();
    if( mysqli_num_rows($dataQuery) ) {
        $data = $dataQuery->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
    };

    add_action("bbp_theme_before_topic_author" , "insertSocialShare");
    function insertSocialShare(){
        global $data;
        if($data['shareButton']){
            echo "hello";
        }
     }

?>
```

I know the program working fine, because I'm already tried it inside functions.php inside theme folder. But, I do not want insert code in functions.php theme folder. I want to run all the program only in my plugin folder.

I'm already tried to, insert connection code, delete require 'connection.php'; and change it to require functions.php like this:

```
require 'nameofweb/wp-content/themes/mythemes/functions.php';
```

But not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should first create your own custom WordPress plugin. Create a new folder inside your `wp-content/plugins/` directory. Create a PHP file with the same name as the directory name, ie.

`wp-content/plugins/my-first-plugin/my-first-plugin.php`.

Now add a plugin header comment in your newly created php file. This is a specially formatted PHP block comment that contains metadata about the plugin, such as its name, author, version, license, etc. Here's an example:

```
<?php
/**
 * Plugin Name: My First Plugin
 * Plugin URI: http://www.mywebsite.com/my-first-plugin
 * Description: The very first plugin that I have ever created.
 * Version: 1.0
 * Author: Your Name
 * Author URI: http://www.mywebsite.com
 */
```

Then add your code below that. After you save the file, you should be able to see your plugin listed and you can enable it in admin dashboard. Enabling your plugin will allow you to use your functions, actions and shortcodes in any WordPress template.

If you're going to start coding your own plugins, I highly suggest you familiarize yourself with how actions and filters work and which ones are available for you to use in [the API Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API#Hooks.2C_Actions_and_Filters).

[The Plugin Handbook](https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/) is also very valuable for anything related to Wordpress Plugins.

For interacting with WP database you could [use $wpdb](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wpdb/). This class is used to interact with the WordPress database without needing to use raw SQL statements.

Comment: Ah, I see. I found the solution thanks to your answer. All i need to do is to create functions.php, inside functions.php have many wordpress hook such as add_action(). and require 'functions.php' inside my-first-plugin.php. 

in nutshell, its about wordpress default. The code will run if have the same name, i mean the folder plugin name and file name.